# is it possible to change the text of boolean field?

Tags: azure-devops, boolean, workitem

While using Azure devops, adding a boolean field to a work item, it appear as either true/false. i want to change it to different text (for example: "in progress/finish"). is it possible? if so how?

thanks!

Comment: If you want to appear as in progress/finish, you need to use `Picklist (string)` type field.

Comment: Not get your latest information, if the below answer is helpful, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to change it to different text (for example: "in
> progress/finish"). is it possible?

I'm afraid this is impossible. The boolean type field only supports `true/false` value and the field appears as a checkbox in the work item form.

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops#add-a-checkbox-field) you can refer to:

> The field appears as a checkbox in the work item form. Check the box
> to indicate a True value. If you display the field on the Kanban or
> Taskboard, then the field values of True and False display (not a
> checkbox).

So if you want to appear as `in progress/finish`, you need to use `Picklist (string)` type field.

[image]